# Couldn't find iframe on test case

Tags: css, selenium, robotframework

I have this test case:

```
Select Frame    id=coach_frame63454108.cf1
Wait Until Element Is Visible       ${ap.gui.header.appname}
Page Should Contain Element         ${ap.gui.header.appname}
Page Should Contain Element         ${ap.gui.header.appnum}
Page Should Contain Element         ${ap.gui.header.procnum}
```

But always have the following error:

```
Element with locator 'coach_frame63454108.cf1' not found.
```

The iframe HTML code is:

```
<iframe id="coach_frame63454108.cf1" style="border: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block" title="Verify Application"></iframe>
```

Could anybody help me please.

Comment: Try to switch instead of selecting because it is a frame or you can try for some other locators like xpath if there is a problem with `.`

Comment: @AliCSE I already try other locaters and the result is the same. How can I switch instead of selecting

Comment: You can try like this `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'coach_frame')]"'))`

Comment: To switch back to main window again, you can try `driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Comment: For more info [Refer This Link](https://www.techbeamers.com/switch-between-iframes-selenium-python/)

Comment: @AliCSE the `Select Frame` keyword is Robotframework's wrapper over selenium's `switch_to()`.

Comment: Oh...! Thank you @Todor Minakov. I don't know that...

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced a similar issue, waiting for the frame to be visible had solved it so you can try like given below -

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible    id=coach_frame63454108.cf1
Select Frame    id=coach_frame63454108.cf1
Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${ap.gui.header.appname}
Page Should Contain Element    ${ap.gui.header.appname}
Page Should Contain Element    ${ap.gui.header.appnum}
Page Should Contain Element    ${ap.gui.header.procnum}
```

Also, before selecting a frame, please ensure to unselect any previously selected frame.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I already try that and didn't work. The error was: Element 'id=coach_frame63454108.cf1' not visible after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to call [`Unselect Frame`](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Unselect%20Frame) first, to reset to the main frameset - the browser may already be in a frame, in that case `Select Frame` would be looking for a sub-frame.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I already try that and didn't work too.